# For SXSSFSheet autofilter is not working for Sheetname with bigger numeric values

Tags: java, apache-poi, worksheet-function, autofilter

I am using Apache poi 4.1.1 for SXSSFSheet. When calling sheet2.setAutoFilter(new CellRangeAddress(2,2,0,17)); internally the poi library validates sheetname. For this it group the letters and digits separately and tries to parse them. Eg. For sheetname AB00000000000000000011, it will split into AB and 00000000000000000011.Tried to adjust the range for autofilter. Tried to to change version of poi library.However the parsing logic for digit is as below in library which throws NumberFormatExcpetion for bigger values. Is there an alternative to set filter for worksheets with bigger sheet names.In org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellReference.java in method isRowWithinRange it is trying to do Long.parseLong(rowStr) throwing exception for bigger values.
`your text`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.